# SPSS Merging Data with duplicate Keys

Tags: merge, syntax, spss

I am currently attempting to join 2 datasets using SPSS syntax but am struggling as I have duplicate values on the keys.  I would like for the joined data to be duplicated for each instance of the key on the source dataset (or other way round as it doesn't matter which is the source).

The datasets are like the following -

*Data1 (3rd column placeholder)*

| batch | run | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 1 |
| A | 3 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 1 |
| C | 2 | 1 |
| D | 1 | 1 |
| E | 1 | 1 |

*Data2*

| batch | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 21 |
| A | 2 | 22 |
| A | 3 | 23 |
| A | 4 | 24 |
| B | 5 | 25 |
| B | 6 | 26 |
| B | 7 | 27 |
| B | 8 | 28 |
| C | 9 | 29 |
| C | 10 | 30 |
| C | 11 | 31 |
| C | 12 | 32 |
| D | 13 | 33 |
| D | 14 | 34 |
| D | 15 | 35 |
| D | 16 | 36 |
| E | 17 | 37 |
| E | 18 | 38 |
| E | 19 | 39 |
| E | 20 | 40 |

**Current attempt**

What I have just now is a method where I CASETOVARS on Data1 before matching it onto Data2 and then VARSTOCASES to expand it out.  This works perfectly with my test data but, unfortunately, it requires that I know exactly how many 'runs' there will be.  That will not be known in production.  It could be 1 or more.

Is there a method to join these datasets while expanding the joined data into the multliple cases in the source?

I am open to using macros but am not able to utilise Python solutions for this (which would probably be easier!).

edit - Unfortunately, extensions are also not possible for me to use.

```
CASESTOVARS
    /ID = batch .

DATASET ACTIVATE data2 .
MATCH FILES
    /FILE = *
    /TABLE = data1
    /BY batch .
EXECUTE .

VARSTOCASES
    /MAKE run FROM BATCH_RUN_ID.1 TO BATCH_RUN_ID.3 .
EXECUTE .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Python and dependent extention command are not availabe, here's an idea how to solve the dynamic list length for the `varstocases` phase.
What you'll do is basically to create a new dataset with the maximum number of runs possible, attach your read dataset to it, and then set the `varstocases` to go for that maximum number of runs (blank rows are dropped automatically):

```
dataset name orig.
data list free/throwthisrow (f1) BATCH_RUN_ID.1 to BATCH_RUN_ID.50 (50F8.2) .
begin data 
1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
end data.
add files /file=* /file=orig .
EXECUTE.
select if missing(throwthisrow).
VARSTOCASES
    /MAKE run FROM BATCH_RUN_ID.1 TO BATCH_RUN_ID.50 /drop throwthisrow.
EXECUTE .
```

Comment: This is a fantastically creative solution.  I don't have much experience with SPSS yet but am learning that it can be more flexible than it appears.  Convincing my workplace to allow Python in the process will really help but in the mean-time this will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

To complete your present approach you can use `spssinc select variables` extention command (see examples of use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48106099/determining-total-frequency-of-a-numeric-id-with-several-id-and-frequency-column/48108735#48108735) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67996321/loop-for-automated-formatting-of-variables-in-spss/67997256#67997256) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54461075/selecting-variables-based-on-partial-names/54464676#54464676)). You will use it to automatically create a list of the variables you want to name in your `varstocases` command, so that the syntax will automatically adapt itself to the number of runs in the data:

So after varstocases and match files:

```
spssinc select variables macroname="!from" /properties pattern = "BATCH_RUN_ID".
VARSTOCASES /MAKE run FROM !from .
```

Comment: For a completely different approach you can look up `stats cartprod`.

Comment: Thank you for your response eli.  Unfortunately this is the 3rd time I've edited this comment as I've discovered that the Stats processor that runs our syntax does not have the extension and it will be a headache to get it fixed (heavily regulated industry).  It did work perfectly locally though!
Are you aware of any other method?  I've read clues to the use of looping and macros but haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: See my new answer for non-Python dependent solution.